# Generic DataTemplate used in multiple GridViewColumns

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, datatemplate

I have a GridView that displays some values:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyDataSource}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Date1" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Date1}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Date2" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Date2}" />
            ...other Columns, not necessarily containing dates...
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

This works fine. Now I want to create a data template that formats a date in a specific way:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MySpecialDate">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding StringFormat={}{0:yyyy.MM.dd}}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Adding `CellTemplate` won't work as long as `DisplayMemberBinding` is specified. Thus, I have to remove the `DisplayMemberBinding` attribute:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Date1" CellTemplate="{StaticResource MySpecialDate}" />
<GridViewColumn Header="Date2" CellTemplate="{StaticResource MySpecialDate}" />
```

**Here's the question**: Now that `DisplayMemberBinding` is gone, how do I tell the GridView which property to display? `GridViewColumn` does not have a `DataContext` property.

Of course, I could put the name of the property (`Date1` resp. `Date2`) into the DataTemplate, but then I would need one template for each property and that would defeat the whole purpose of having a *template*.

```
<!-- I don't want that -->
<DataTemplate x:Key="MySpecialDate1">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date1, StringFormat={}{0:yyyy.MM.dd}}" />
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="MySpecialDate2">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date2, StringFormat={}{0:yyyy.MM.dd}}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: I often ask myself the same question, and I haven't found a satisfying answer yet...

Comment: (Note: haven't tried.) Is it possible to _re_define the default DataTemplate for a type (target DateTime)?  Also, DisplayMemberBinding should allow StringFormat.  Does that not work for DisplayMemberBinding?

Comment: @jberger: Yes, StringFormat works for DisplayMemberBinding, that's the workaround I am using currently. However, that requires me to specify the format redundantly for every date. I'll have a look at the default template approach tomorrow and report back...

Comment: @Heinzi: I tried defining a default DataTemplate and it seems to work when binding to a ContentControl.  However, the DisplayMemberBinding seems to inflate with a TextBlock and call .ToString().

Answer (score 1):

Related to your question is mine: [Pass multiple resources into a DataTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10210519) which I finally found a solution for.
I think you cannot get around the definition of a template for every such date. But depending on the complexity of your display template this solution keeps the additional `DataTemplate`s code to a minimum:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DateX">
  <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MySpecialDate}" local:YourClass.AttachedDate="DateX"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

These additional `DataTemplate`s use an attached property which can then be used by a converter in the `DataTemplate` "MySpecialDate".
The attached property has to be defined in the code behind. The answer to my own question contains a [complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10231426/275195).

Answer (score 0):

If the format is really that widely used, then you could use the following

In `DateTimeColumn.cs`

```
public class DateTimeColumn : GridViewColumn
{
    protected override void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPropertyChanged(e);
        if (Equals(e.PropertyName, "DisplayMemberBinding") && DisplayMemberBinding != null)
        {
            DisplayMemberBinding.StringFormat = "{0:yyyy.MM.dd}";
        }
    }
}
```

`XAML code...`

```
<local:DateTimeColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Date1}" />
```

(I don't like the format as a magic string, but the code can be modified as needed.)