# XAML: Same Template, Different Bindings

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, datatemplate

I am trying to create a `ListView` with a `GridView` that has 2 columns: Name and Date, which are to be binded to a Person `Object` later on.

I want to use a `DataTemplate`, this template consists of a `Label`.

My problem is I want to use this template for both columns, but the content of the label is to be bind to a different property in each column. In short, I want to be able to bind the content of the label, in the `GridViewColumn` code block and not in the `DataTemplate` code block.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I think it would be helpful to show your XAML layout.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/q/8328443/1860561](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8328443/1860561).

Comment: Seems like using the same `DataTemplate` for multiple column bindings is a dead end unless if you use different templates. If you can use `DisplayMemberBinding` property instead, then you can do what you want by setting the column binding to be the Name or Date property of the Person object.

Comment: @gitsitgo If I used `DisplayMemberBinding` then I would not be able to use the `DataTemplate` I created earlier. What I did for now - and not satisfied with - is create a template with a `Binding` to the Date, and another template with a `Binding` to the Name.

And yes I think my question is a duplicate of the one you mentioned. Should I delete my question now?

Comment: If none of the answers in the duplicate satisfy you, then... I think  (I'm fairly new here too)... you can just leave this one open. 

Is there any reason you have to use a `DataTemplate`? Unless if you are adding _more_ than one control in the `DataTemplate`, `DisplayMemberBinding` effectively does the same thing and it lets you bind in your `GridViewColumn` and should work well for one label in a grid view item.

Answer (score 1):

I tried it this way with empty binding in datatemplate which solved in my case..(didn't checked for object types with more than one property to be binded). This will work in the case of this question's context.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="commonTemplate">
    <Label Content="{Binding}" />
</DataTemplate>

<GridViewColumn>
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Name}"
                ContentTemplate="{StaticResource commonTemplate}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>

<GridViewColumn>
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Date}"
                ContentTemplate="{StaticResource commonTemplate}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

Any better way or improvements are always welcome.. thank you